# How to Change Inbox view in outlook

Tags: outlook

As shown in below image i have this view in outllook [image]

But Automatically/By Mistake view has changed like this(as shown in below images) so how to set like previous view[image]

and i tried like this but Middle Pane (Marked Area) is not worked or not looking like previous view[image: i'am asking about highlighted thing in image]

Comment: you can change the "Reading Pane" in view

Comment: @RahulShukla I edited 3rd image , I want middle pane (Highlighted thing in 3rd image) should be look like previous view, and i try to changing in "Reading Pane" but i didnt get expected view

Answer (score 1):

The view is the compact view. I was able to get back to it by:

View Settings -> Other settings -> Checkmark the "Use compact layout in widths..."

If needed drag the reading pane to make the messages smaller (compact view).

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook view - the reading pane depends on the item type selected in the list. On the first screenshot you've selected a meeting request and on the last one I see a regular mail item.

Comment: I want middle pane (Highlighted thing in 3rd image) should be look like previous view, but can u observe first image middle pane and third image pane is different, both are not same

Comment: You are free to set up any view. On the `View` tab click the `Change view` button and customize the current view according to your needs.